# How to log all requests in Actix-Web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

Is there a way to log all requests being received by actix-web irrespective of whether the endpoint exists or not?

It seems I need to use middleware for this, is this the recommended approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is logging middleware available as part of `actix_web`: [`actix_web::middleware::Logger`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.2.1/actix_web/middleware/struct.Logger.html)

> `Middleware` for logging request and response info to the terminal. `Logger` middleware uses standard `log` crate to log information.

Middleware is called for each request (so long no other middleware or route handles it beforehand), so putting it on your `App` at the top level should get all requests, whether the endpoint exists or not.

```
use actix_web::{middleware::Logger, App};

let app = App::new()
    .wrap(Logger::default())
    // ...
```

Comment: You need to enable a logging implementation too: `env_logger::init_from_env(env_logger::Env::new().default_filter_or("info"));`

Comment: @jrpear Right, I forget that not everyone knows the `log` crate just provides a facade and you need to initialize a logging implementation of your choosing based on where and how the log messages should be sent. Env-logger is a common one but others can be seen at: [available logging implementations](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/#available-logging-implementations).

Comment: I've made a fork of the original logger in this crate [actix-contrib-logger](https://crates.io/crates/actix-contrib-logger), that allows to customize a bit more the level to print out HTTP requests, and the errors in the requests as well. Moreover, by default server errors (HTTP 5xx) are printed with `ERROR` severity.